# Can't delete a node from the root level

Tags: javascript, gun

*gun 0.8.8, Node.js-to-Node.js, Node.js-to-browser*

Create a node (Node.js)

```
let node = gun.get(`watcher/f0de26c0-a29f-11e7-8661-154b982951a4`);
node.put({
  stats: {
    num: 13
  },
  name: 'trex'
});
```

Delete the node (Node.js)

```
node.put(null);
```

Check if the node exists (Node.js)

```
node.get('stats').val(function (v, k) {
  console.log('task', task);
  console.log('k:', k);
  console.log('v:', v);
});
```

**The node and all its properties still exist!**

```
task f0de26c0-a29f-11e7-8661-154b982951a4
k: stats
v: { _: { '#': 'j949102jDUdSklGduZh8', '>': { num: 1508926521878 } },
  num: 13 }
```

Check if the node exists (browser)

```
gun.get('watcher/f0de26c0-a29f-11e7-8661-154b982951a4').get('stats').val((v, k) => console.log(JSON.stringify(v)))
VM604:1 {"_":{"#":"j949102jDUdSklGduZh8",">":{"num":1508926521878}},"num":13}
```

Try to delete the node again (browser)

```
gun.get('watcher/f0de26c0-a29f-11e7-8661-154b982951a4').put(null)
gun.js:825 Data saved to the root level of the graph must be a node (an object), not a object of "null"!
```

Is it possible to delete a root level node completely?

Why there is no warning message when I try to delete it from Node.js?

What is the not root level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't.  You can empty the node... gun.get( "rootNode" ).put( null );

Or you can add a top layer node like 'dbRoot' and put everyone one layer deeper than the root.

A way that might work...

- Start a new gun instance that connects to the first, and does a map of all nodes except the one you want to delete.
- Close both servers, move the data.json to the original one
- Restart the server.